# Lie's 3rd theorem

Tags: manifolds, definition, lie-groups, lie-algebras, connectedness

Lie's 3rd theorem says that

> For any Lie algebra ${\frak g}$, there exists a connected and simply connected group $G$ which algebra is (isomorphic to) ${\frak g}$

My problem is that I don't understand what does 'connected and simply connected' stand for? Since Lie groups have a manifold structure, does 'simply connected' refer to the idea of Jordan curves (closed curves that are homotopic to an inside point)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space

Comment: It's a topological space: "connected" means it's one piece and "simply connected" means it does not have holes (roughly speaking).

Comment: @NickD Then, can we ensure that if a space is simply connected it has to be connected? Or is there some nuance and that's why both concepts appear in the theorem?

Comment: Simple connectedness requires path connectedness (which is a stronger version of connectedness - see the Wikipedia page in the first comment above). But a space can be connected without being simply connected (one piece with a hole, e.g. a torus). But maybe the book uses slightly different definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If a topological space is connected, we say that it is simply connected if every closed path is homotopic to a constant path.